# How to get out of GRUB in UNIX

Tags: grub

What is this screen?? How can I quit this and get into my unix system.
I am using oracle virtualbox on a MAC. Please Someone Help Me With This!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When sth's wrong, I know, grub starts at rescue mode. You may change the partition info, or modify grub menu etc.

This link would be helpful:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition